# Not sorting keys when creating an dictionary fromkeys

Tags: python

When creating a dictionary from keys:

```
mydict = dict.fromkeys(['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8', 'c9', 'c10', 'c11'], np.linspace(-1.2, -0.8, num=5))
```

I get the keys sorted beforehand:

```
'c1': array([-1.2, -1.1, -1. , -0.9, -0.8]),
'c10': array([-1.2, -1.1, -1. , -0.9, -0.8]),
'c11': array([-1.2, -1.1, -1. , -0.9, -0.8]),
'c2': array([-1.2, -1.1, -1. , -0.9, -0.8]),
...
```

How to get the dictionary with entries in the order as given in the list?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the typical python `dict` does not allow you to define the order of its keys. If you want to do that, you need to use a `OrderedDict`. The necessary would be quiet small.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
mydict = OrderedDict.fromkeys(['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8', 'c9', 'c10', 'c11'], np.linspace(-1.2, -0.8, num=5))
```

I can also strongly hint at looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537308/10833207 with a way better explanation how dict key ordering works in python, especially for its different versions.